# Making two-finger scrolling work on my ThinkPad L480

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I'm running 16.04.4 on my ThinkPad L480 and am having a great out of the box experience. Then only thing I'm missing ist two finger scrolling with the touchpad. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, 1st we'll see the touchpad model and it's associated driver requirement:

1. `xinput-list` will show your touchpad model as Virtual Core Pointer (in my case, it shows `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`)
2. So, I have to install it's associated driver: `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
3. Now issuing `synclient -l` command will show available touchpad options
4. In the output, check if "VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0"
    & "HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0", if so, your Two finger scroll is not active.
5. Create an empty file at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` and paste this:

`Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
        Option "TapButton3" "2"
        Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
        Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
        Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
        Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
        Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
        Option "FingerLow" "30"
        Option "FingerHigh" "50"
        Option "MaxTapTime" "125"
        ...
EndSection`

edit as needed and save the file.

6. Reboot.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution to your issue, there is a program called *TouchEgg* that users have been using to program touchpad gestures on Ubuntu. Here is a link that provides a guide on how to enable two finger scrolling using TouchEgg. I know it may be targeting Magic Pad users but the way the guide implemented the features may also apply to your situation.

[How to Add Mac-Like Multi-Touch Gestures to Ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-multitouch-gestures-ubuntu/)

To view more information including troubleshooting issues with running TouchEgg on Ubuntu 16.04 visit the GitHub [FAQ Page](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/wiki/FAQ) of TouchEgg where it's addressed.